# Removing a Selective Section from a String

Tags: c#, regex, split, tokenize

I need help figuring out how to remove only the very last `"</span>"` tag from a string. He is an example of what one of the strings might look like, but sometimes there are a few

```
<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center"><span style="text-decoration:underline;"> some text   </span> </span></DIV>
```

Comment: Write your own mini parser that iterates over the string and checks for the presence and position of `</span>`

Comment: Use LastIndexOf("</span>") method to find index number for </span> then remove it from string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878133/delete-the-last-instance-of-a-certain-string-from-a-text-file-without-changing-t

Comment: Do you want to prevent user entering HTML that will interrupt the content, other than simply remove *that particular `</span>`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var originalString = @"<DIV style='TEXT-ALIGN: center'><span style='text-decoration:underline;'> some text   </span> </span></DIV>";

        var lastIndex = originalString.LastIndexOf("</span>");

        var newwString = originalString.Substring(0, lastIndex) + originalString.Substring(lastIndex + 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `</span>(?=[(</span>)])`